# How to pass variables to an asynchronous callback function that will remain intact?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I am using the Google Maps JS API to Geocode some addresses, but I need to have access to a number of variables inside the callback of the geocode function.  The geocoder is an asynchronous function.

My code is as follows:

```
for (var prop in markerData) {
    geocoder.geocode( { address: addressData }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            console.log(addressData);

            markerInfo = { 
                lat: lat, 
                lng: lng,
                firstname: markerData[prop].firstname,
                lastname: markerData[prop].lastname,
                company: markerData[prop].company,
                addressFormatted: addressData,
                street: markerData[prop].street,
                city: markerData[prop].city,
                postcode: markerData[prop].postcode,
                telephone: markerData[prop].telephone
            }

            markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                title: markerData[prop].firstname + ' ' + markerData[prop].lastname,
                markerInfo: markerInfo
            });

            markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
                updateInfo(this.markerInfo);
            });

            $.get('cache.php', {
                address: addressData,
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`addressData` is always the value of the last entry of `markerData`.  `markerData` data is definitely correct.

I need a way of passing both `addressData` and `markerData` to the `geocoder.geocode` function that will be accessible inside the callback.

Comment: You may want to surround the call with an IIFE. That way the variable passed will remain the same inside.

Comment: I'm unsure why this has been marked as a duplicate, especially with the linked question.  It's a different issue found under different circumstances.  Just because a problem has the same answer doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for my comment:

```
for (var prop in markerData) {
    (function(addressData){
        geocoder.geocode( { address: addressData }, function(results, status) {
            //Other code
        });
    })(addressData);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Never heard of an IIFE before, will read up on it.  Thank you